# How do you sketch a B-spline basis function?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm presented with the question on the practice exam:

> Sketch the curve and control points for the cubic B-spline basis
>   function N^3_2 over the knot sequence with 8 knots, full multiplicity
>   at the ends, and simple knots in between.

There is almost no information about it in the book. I understand what a cubic B-spline curve is, but I'm not sure I understand the basis function. In the "N^3_2", I'm assuming the "3" is the degree, but I don't know what the "2" represents. The knot sequence should be something like:

|||-----|-----|-----|||

As I understand it, but what is the final sketch supposed to be?

This is for one of my Computer Science classes, but if someone knows of a better forum, please let me know.

Comment: If you've been given this as an exercise in your class, it's probably doable.  Have you reviewed relevant material from your course & textbook?  Do you understand it?  Can you explain more specifically what your confusion is?  Do you know what a cubic spline is?  Do you know what the cubic B-spline basis function N^3_2 is?  Can you formulate a more precise technical question?  Open-ended questions like this tend not to be a good fit for the StackExchange format.  The same is true of questions that just copy-paste a class exercise.

Comment: I updated my question with more details on what I am confused about.